# Update array in forEach angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am having a problem when trying to filter an array in angular. I'm using typescript.

I have a parent page that contains a directive. The directive has a property of an Array of items which it displays in a datatable.

On the parent page, I want to filter the list that is being passed to the directive. Here is how I am doing it....

```
<table items="vm.items"></table>
```

In my parent controller, I have a button which when you press it executes the following function:

```
applyFilters() {
   var filteredItems=[];
   this.items.forEach((value, key) => {
      if (value.item!== 'test') {
         this.filteredItems.push(value);
      }
   });
   console.log(this.filteredItems);
   this.items = this.filteredItems;
}
```

But the value in the directive does not update when I update the filter?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `this.filteredItems` != `var filteredItems`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 if (value.item!== 'test') {
     this.filteredItems.push(value);
 }
```

The variable `filteredItems` is defined through `var filteredItems = [];`, while you assign through `this.filteredItems`. Just use:

```
filteredItems.push(value);
...
this.items = filteredItems;
```

Comment: Also he probably has `this.filteredItems` defined. He should delete that.

Comment: I still can get it to update the table in the directive. It looks like this now. <code> export class Controller implements IController { items: Models.IItem[];
        filteredItems: Models.IItem[];applyFilters() {

            this.items.forEach((value, key) => {
                if (value.category!== 'test') {
                    this.filteredItems.push(value);
                }
            });

          //  this.Items= this.filteredItems
        }} <code>  this.items is still not updating in the view

Comment: The array itself is getting updated , but the property in the directive is not.

Comment: Well, maybe put some JSFiddle will help a lot. I cannot so figure out what you mean...